# How do I use Arrayformula with a Match function that uses a dynamic range in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

in col `A` I have a list of email addresses
in col `B` I want to catch duplicates, so if an email address in A appeared before I get a trigger in `B`. 
I'm using this formula which works great:
`=if(isna(match(a3,$A$2:A2,0)),"New","Duplicate")`

note that as I drag this formula, `$A$2` stays so the range grows (e.g. for cell `B51` the range will be from `$A$2:A50`)

My problem is that since column `A` updates automatically (e.g. new email addresses are added) I want column `B` to update automatically as well. I tried using Arrayformula but can't figure it out :( 
I tried both: 
`=arrayformula(if(isna(match(A3:A,$A$2:A2,0)),"New","Duplicate"))`
and
`=arrayformula(if(isna(match(A3:A,$A$2:A2:A,0)),"New","Duplicate"))`
 but they don't work.

here's a spreadsheet with an example and my (failing) attempts to solve it
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N3pFPnT452FmWa9w8EkYpIq-ZnivjoCzt5ORrNEKgLQ/edit#gid=0

Comment: Why don't you remove duplicates when you update the email list?

Comment: It's for reporting so I need both, how many New emails and how many are repeating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please, try:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(if(VLOOKUP(A2:A,{A2:A,ROW(A2:A)},2,)=ROW(A2:A), "New", "Duplicate")))`

If matching row = current row → "New", else → "Duplicate".

I used `vlookup` because it may be used with `ArrayFormula`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using Match to see if the first match for the current email address is before the current row of the array

```
=arrayformula(if(match(A2:index(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),A2:index(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),0)<row(A2:index(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)))-1,"Duplicate","New"))
```

[image]

Comment: Worked great, but recently I found out something strange, I have it on 3 different sheets, in 1 it behaves as expected, but in the other 2 it doesn't update the formula all the way to the bottom. in one case it only works for 15566 of the emails out of 15743 and in another case it works for 18063 out of 18243. It's not a matter of size since in the file it works it works on over 25000 emails. Any ideas?

Comment: It's probably because there are some blank cells in the list of emails. I'm using COUNTA to see where the data ends to try and make it more efficient, but it only works if there are no empty cells. You could simplify it and where I've put A2:INDEX... just put A2:A, but not sure what impact it would have on performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a countif that looks at everything above the current row:

`=IF(countif($A$1:A2,A2)>1,"DUPLICATE","NEW")`

[image]

Comment: Thanks and it's a very elegant take, but when I add the arrayformula it breaks (if an email repeats twice than the first one is also marked as "Duplicate")
`=arrayformula(IF(countif($A$1:A2:A,A2:A)>1,"Duplicate","New"))`